# What is this hand tool with handles similar to a spokeshave? It has different selectable profiles around the edge of a disc

Tags: wood, hand-tools, molding

[image]

Can anyone identify this? Woodworking tool?

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I've never seen a scratch stock quite like it. Although scratch tools were and are commercially available they were often [made by the craftsman](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/how-do-i-achieve-inset-edge-beading/5148#5148) since all the materials needed were on hand in an average workshop — a scrap of wood, a couple of screws and some saw steel. So this could be a user-made tool, although to a higher standard than most, or a commercial offering. Unusual and rare I think, regardless of source.

Comment: Jordan, users can't use SE as a sales tool, and my edit to remove your eBay link just reflects this. You can't now edit the Question because you don't like this; once a Question is posted to SE it becomes community property (hence why other members with sufficient rep are allowed to edit them).

Comment: Noted  - New to this - Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it! - Windsor Beader Type 1 - 1885

Comment: With more details here: http://thevalleywoodworker.blogspot.com/2017/02/scratch-stock.html

Answer (score 9):

This looks like a beading scratch-stock.

Beading is a decorative detail added to the edges of boards to make them less prone to damage and to hide gaps in joinery or around doors.  This tool creates them by scraping the workpiece with the metal blade.  This is not a "cutting" operation because the blade is held perpendicular with the workpiece.  In this case there are several different profiles that you could choose from by rotating the metal piece in the center.